# Using piklist meta box, strange behavior

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I'm trying to get into wordpress theme development. I currently work at agency which uses Roots framework and piklist.

I created a custom post type into which i wanted to add an icon from font-awesome.
I wanted a more userfriendly approach in the select box inside the metabox container.

i was suggested this: https://github.com/tommusrhodus/FontAwesome-4.3.0-Class-Names/blob/master/array.php

Which I got to work somewhat, the select box has more user friendly names for the classes, however i have trouble outputing them. This is the code i use for outputing it:

```
    $font_awesome_icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'font-awesome-icon'); 
    <i class="fa <?php echo $font_awesome_icon; ?>"></i>
```

This is what i get in the output:

```
<i class="fa <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in  <b>/home/html/grg.sk/public_html/_sub/dusan/dummytest/wp-       content/themes/theme/templates/blocks/block-aboutus.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
Array"></i>
```

However if i add array with any attributes (that don't even exist suddenly it works. I found this out by mistake when adding array to the wrong line of code... :)

```
$font_awesome_icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'font-awesome-icon',array('size' => 'whatever'));
```

So can please anyone explain to me why this doesn't work?

I could also include the thread from piklist, but i'm not sure if that's allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default get_post_meta() returns an array. Set the last parameter to true to return the value of the meta data.

[See the codex as a reference >](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Your code should be:

```
$font_awesome_icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'font-awesome-icon', true);
```

Comment: Yep, this works!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/tommusrhodus/FontAwesome-4.3.0-Class-Names/blob/master/array.php), that font awesome class has many values stored in an array. To use the `font-awesome-icon` you have to show the array, which is why your code

```
$font_awesome_icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'font-awesome-icon',array('size' => 'whatever'));
```

works fine even if there is no value. I would suggest you provide the appropriate "fa" in index, and it's value, like:

```
'no-icon'   => 'No-Icon',
'fa-adjust' => 'Adjust',
```

If you try outputting it without the array, you will definitely get an error of array to string conversion because the value does not belong to the string family either or not imploded.